# what is the sequence of threads in java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is very simple program of java multithreading which I have written for understanding the concept of Java multithreading.

```
public class test extends Thread {

    void test1(){
        System.out.println("this method is just for calling thread");
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i =0; i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println("Thread One "+i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread 1 Interrupted ");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting Thread one");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        test t1= new test();
        t1.test1();

        try{
            for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                System.out.println("Thread Two "+i);
                Thread.sleep(200);

            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread Two Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting Thread Two");
    }
}
```

When I execute above program I get below output:

```
this method is just for calling thread
Thread Two 1
Thread One 0
Thread Two 2
Thread Two 3
Thread Two 4
Thread Two 5
Thread One 1
Thread Two 6
Thread Two 7
Thread Two 8
Thread Two 9
Thread Two 10
Thread One 2
Exiting Thread Two
Thread One 3
Thread One 4
Thread One 5
Exiting Thread one
```

So from above output can anyone please explain me why second thread is executing first.

Comment: You can't predict thread the behaviour until you synchronize it.

Comment: Thread scheduling is handled by the OS. If you want predictable execution order, by far the easiest way is to use a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first two lines : 
Thread Two 1
Thread One 0
order can be anything as you have started a thread and moved on. but generally you will get Thread Two 1 first because it will take some time to start Thread rather than moving to the next line.

Now whenever thread one is run you are sleeping it for 1000 ms. and sleeping main thread for 200ms. 
So, after this, Thread two will run 5(200*5) times before thread one is executed again because sleep method is asynchronous call. 
Hence it will print : 
Thread Two 2
Thread Two 3
Thread Two 4
Thread Two 5
Thread One 1

Now after this step again same thing happens. Thread one is in sleep for 1000ms. 
so after every 200ms we receive output of : 
Thread Two 6 (This will come at glance with Thread One 1)
Thread Two 7
Thread Two 8
Thread Two 9
Thread Two 10

Now this cycle repeats and this output is printed.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

You can run thread 1 before thread 2 using join:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
test t1= new test();
t1.test1();
try {
    t1.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try{
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
        System.out.println("Thread Two "+i);
        Thread.sleep(200);

    }

}
catch(InterruptedException e){
    System.out.println("Thread Two Interrupted");
}
System.out.println("Exiting Thread Two");
```

}

Comment: Thanks @ Damanpreet Singh.
Is there any way to get output that will start from Thread One 0.

Comment: Updated my answer.
output is  : 
this method is just for calling thread
Thread One 0
Thread One 1
Thread One 2
Thread One 3
Thread One 4
Thread One 5
Exiting Thread one
Thread Two 1
Thread Two 2
Thread Two 3
Thread Two 4
Thread Two 5
Thread Two 6
Thread Two 7
Thread Two 8
Thread Two 9
Thread Two 10
Exiting Thread Two
I guess this helps. If it helps please accept the answer :)

Comment: If you're waiting for thread 1 to finish before running thread 2, you don't need threads at all

Comment: Thanks I got this. but what I have to say is that I don't want to change the schedule of the threads. It must be executed as per sleep time starting from thread one, for example Thread One 0 then it will sleep for 1000 ms and call will go to Thread Two 1, Thread Two 2 till Thread one wakes up from sleep and it will execute Thread One 1 and so on.

Comment: Parvez that is decided by OS. There are two ways to achieve this with your current implementation.
1. Put Thread.sleep(200); before your for loop. 
2. You can use wait notify for this. in your test1() method before start() you can take a lock on object. 
3. And put your for loop in synchronized block with same object that you locked in test1 and it will wait until notify is not called on that object. 
4. Call notify on your object once your work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Having two or more processes running, which depend on each other being in a certain state at certain times without being synchronized is actually a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Since threads can - ever since the introduction of multicore CPUs - actually run in parallel, there is absolutely no predictability on which thread will "start first", i.e. which thread will manage to get its output done first.

Comment: But every time execute the same program I get same output.

Comment: As per sequence first call is going to test1() and in test1() there is start method which will start the run program. so Thread One 0 must be executed before Thread Two 1.

Comment: @Parvez the start() call is non-blocking so as soon as it does what it is supposed to it continues to execute Thread 2 thus entering the loop and Printing your text. There is no guarantee that the newly started thread goes first as already stated. Afterwards the output goes as is since you are using different intervals for sleep causing thread two to run the loop statemens multiple times Before thread one even Wakes from sleep.

Comment: Thanks I got this.
But can you please tell me how to execute Thread One before Thread Two, is there any way to do this.

Comment: If you want thread 1 to run before thread 2 you don't need threads

Comment: Unless what you mean is that you want to guarantee thread 1 /starts/ before thread 2?

Comment: Thanks for your response I appreciate it.